# Waiting till Meteor is connected using react-native-meteor

Tags: meteor, react-native

I'm using react-native-meteor to connect to Meteor server. When I run following code, I get the output as the screenshot. Connection doesn't established before the render method is called for the first time. How can I handle this? Can I block till the connection happens? ( onConnection method is not available in the react-native-meteor)

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("GOing to connect");
    Meteor.connect(SERVER_URL);
    console.log("After connect : " + JSON.stringify(Meteor.status()));

  }

  render() {
    console.log(Meteor.status());
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Meteor.user()));
    if (Meteor.status().status === "connected") {
      if (Meteor.user()) {
        return ( <
          TestViewOne / >
        );
      } else {
        return ( <
          TestViewTwo / >
        );
      }
    } else {
      return ( < View > < /View>)
      }

    }
  }
```

[image]

When I use the following code, the Meteor.user() still returns null.

```js
Meteor.ddp.on('connected', function() {
  console.log("on Connected : " + JSON.stringify(Meteor.user()));
  localForceUpdate();
});
```

Comment: Since `Meteor.connect()` is asynchronous it will not block render method to be called. But connect method is being called before the render method is being called. Your log message also says that

Comment: but connection doesn't happen after the first rendering.

Comment: that might be the issue with `Meteor.connect` method. Check the url and other parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the app to render a loading screen until the server is connected using withTracker, this way the main app will not progress to parts that assume the connection has been made:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

    if (!this.appLaunched) {
      if (!this.props.serverConnected || this.props.loggingIn) {
        return <LoadingScreen />;
      }
    }

    this.appLaunched = true; //this prevents the app reloading to front page everytime server reconnects

    return (
      <Root>
        <AppContainer />
      </Root>
    );
  }
}

export default withTracker(params => {
  return {
    loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn(),
    serverConnected: Meteor.status().connected
  };
})(App);
```